# PyQtgraph y axis label non scientific notation

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

PyQtgraph Y axis label is displaying in scientific notation. I do not want it to be in scientific notation. What is the code to change label to non scientific.

[image]

Scientific notation - 1.70 (x1e+06)

non Scientific notation 1700000 (I want to display Y axis in non scientific notation).

from main() function I call addXYZ to add contour lines, then I call Show2dPlot to display the contour map plot.

```
##### add the XY contour line to plot #####       
    def addXYZ(self, X, Y, Z):
        self.plotwin.plot(X, Y, pen=(255,255,255))#cmap=cm.coolwarm)


##### Format 2D Plot #####        
    def Show2dPlot(self):
        self.plotwin.setLogMode(x=False, y=False)
        self.plotwin.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.plotwin.setLabel('left', "Easting")# units='A')
        self.plotwin.setLabel('bottom', "Northing") #, units='s')
        self.plotwin.setAspectLocked()
        self.plotwin.set_scientific(False) #I'm getting error in set_scientific
```

Comment: use `set_scientific(False)`

Comment: @RaminNietzsche I'm getting NameError, PyQtgraph might not have set_scientific. :(

Comment: Can you share some parts of your code?

Answer (score 2):

PyQtgraph does not contain set_scientific(False). The best solution is to override the AxisItem.tickStrings will help to create custom labels.

[image]

Below is the code.

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

##### Override class #####
class NonScientific(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NonScientific, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [int(value*1) for value in values] #This line return the NonScientific notation value

class MyApplication(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Contour plotting")
        self.win.resize(1000,600)

        self.plot = self.win.addPlot(title='Contour', axisItems={'left': NonScientific(orientation='left')})
        self.curve = self.plot.plot()


    def PlotContour(self):
        x = range(50000,60000,10000)#X coordinates of contour
        y = range(500000,600000,100000)#Y coordinates of contour
        self.curve.setData(x=x, y=y)
        self.curve.autoRange()

def main():
    app = MyApplication(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```