# (pyqtgraph) How do I show actual (non-scientific) tick values on a logarithmic Y axis?

Tags: python, pyqt5, subclass, logarithm, pyqtgraph

My first StackOverflow question, apologies for poor format or if this has been asked before (I can't find the answer anywhere). I'm using Python 3 and pyqtgraph.

I want to graph (price) data on a **logarithmic y scale**, but I want to retain the actual values, **not the scientific notation**.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()

myplot = pg.PlotDataItem([1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128])

p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.hideAxis('left')
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.showGrid(y = True, alpha = 1.0)
p1.addItem(myplot)
p1.setLogMode(y=True)

QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

`myplot` is a straight line as intended in logMode, but tick values are scientific:
[image: myplot with logscale]

I modified a subclass from a related question ([PyQtgraph y axis label non scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778148/pyqtgraph-y-axis-label-non-scientific-notation)) and tried to override the AxisItem, but it doesn't seem to 'activate' via myplot. :

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

class NonScientific(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NonScientific, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [int(value*1) for value in values] #This line return the NonScientific notation value

    def logTickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [int(value*1) for value in values] #This line return the NonScientific notation value

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()

myplot = pg.PlotDataItem([1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128], axisItems={'right': NonScientific(orientation='right')})

p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.hideAxis('left')
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.showGrid(y = True, alpha = 1.0)
p1.addItem(myplot)
p1.setLogMode(y=True)

QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

My questions are:

- Am I overriding a subclass correctly? Is AxisItem even the right class to override? If so, is there a way to 'get' the AxisItem of the p1 plotItem? I tried `p1.getAxis('right')` but don't know how to override the class that way
- Is there a way to retain the actual *values* along the y axis in a log scale, rather than simply modifying strings, without transforming to log numbers?

What I mean by question 2 is, I have tried a workaround that is probably the wrong way to do it. I added these lines just before the end:

```
yaxticks = [[(1, '1.00'), (2, '2.00'), (4, '4.00'), (8, '8.00'), (16, '16.00'), (32, '32.00'), (64, '64.00'), (128, '128.00')]]
yax = p1.getAxis('right')
yax.setTicks(yaxticks)
```

As well as tried this:

```
yaxticks = [[(0.1, '1.00'), (0.2, '2.00'), (0.4, '4.00'), (0.8, '8.00'), (1.6, '16.00'), (3.2, '32.00'), (6.4, '64.00'), (12.8, '128.00')]]
```

Results were as follows, compared with original:
[image: 3 tries with logScale]

Based on where those lines are falling, I can tell I could get this to work by referencing the log values at each point, but this seems unpythonic and a band-aid solution. My application works intimately with price data and I worry all graphical functions that reference price data would need to transform to and from log values.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you are doing it the right way. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778148/pyqtgraph-y-axis-label-non-scientific-notation

Comment: Thanks, that's where I copied the Nonscientific custom class from. I guess a simpler question is how do I get that class work? Defining it in myplot is not working.